# Collatz conjuncture and answer format

Tags: python, yield-return, collatz

I am pretty new to python as I just started my masters (in analytics) so bare with me. We are doing the collatz conjecture problem, which from other results on here I can see people are fairly familar with. I understand how to use a while loop to get the the answer and this what I originally had:

```
[IN}:
n = int(input("Please enter a whole greater than number 1 for n: "))

def CollatzC(n):
    print("Starting value is:", n)
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
            print (n)
        else: 
            n = (n*3)+1
            print (n)
    return n


print (CollatzC(n))

[out]:
The starting value is: 10 
5
16
8
4
2
1
1
```

My issue is with the output as my teacher wants the output to look like this:

```
[in]: print((CollatzC(10))
[out]: [10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

I looked on here and saw this answer which does give the desired output but we haven't used "yield" yet and the rule in the class about using "outside functions", for lack of a better term, is you have to be able to thoroughly explain the function/what is happening, your reasoning, and it's results in order for it to not be "cheating".

```
[in]: 
user = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    
def collatz(n):
    print(n)
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
            yield(n)
        else:
            n = n * 3 + 1
            yield(n)

print(list(collatz(user)))
```

SO can someone please explain to me what's going on with this or explain how I could make it work with what I have? Also I understand I may have lose the "The starting value is: " line. I can live without it.

Bonus points if you can tell me why I am getting two 1's at the end!!!

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Append to an initially empty list rather than printing each value of `n`. Return the resulting list. You are seeing two ones since you are both printing and returning that final 1. In general, functions should not contain `print` but should instead work by what they `return`.

Comment: @ john Coleman. Thank you for answering!! Two things. Where am I adding the append? when I take the print out then it doesn't list all the numbers it goes through in the loop though? Also If I define newlist = [], then instead of where print(n) is within the if and else statement  am adding newlist.append(n)?

Comment: The list will contain whatever you append to it. You might need to append the final 1 after the loop, or the initial `n` before the loop; however you structure the code.

Comment: @john coleman I finally got it! Thank you!! My teacher never went over how to use this in While loops!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for this if you still need this. It uses a function to perform the collatz method, and also checks for negative numbers and integers. The beginning of the code initializes the list, and then every function call of collatz appends to it.

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        numlist.append(number // 2)
        return(number // 2)
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        result = 3 * number + 1
        numlist.append(result)
        return(result)

# Program starts here.        
while True:
    try:
        # Ask for input and establish list with said input
        n = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
        numlist = [n]
        # If number is negative or 0, asks for positive and starts over.
        if int(n) < 1:
            print('Please enter a positive INTEGER!')
            continue
        #If number is applicable, goes through collatz function.
        while n != 1:
            n = collatz(int(n))
    # If input is a non-integer, asks for a valid integer starts over.
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid INTEGER!')
    else:
        print(numlist)
        break
```